# The best resources file type for iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring

In my iPhone project, there are a lot of files including: image files, audio files, and text files.

Now the issue is finding the best file type to manage these files. The image files are related with the audio files and the text files.

I need a file that show the relationship of these files.I am currently using `txt` type, but it seems chaotic. I want to use `xls` file type but I can't parse the file correctly.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [PLIST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list). They are easy to read (NSDictionary and NSArray can be created from them) and allow associations to be stored. Also, XCode provides native editing support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I used PLIST befor, but it's not simple to edit it,there are lot of level relationship that means there are a lot of Dictionary or Array.